# How to input punctuation via Google Assistant?

Tags: sms, text-input, google-assistant

Lately I've become a fan of using Google Assistant to dictate text messages.  This works well for hands-free texting; however, I haven't been able to figure out if it's possible to insert punctuation or other non-literal characters.

If I say "Two things colon first let's do this and second let's do that", the content will be `Two things colon first let's do this and second let's do that` when I want it to be `Two things: first let's do this and second let's do that`.  Same with "period" - It always inserts the word `period` and not the character `.`

Is there a way to use punctuation or am I destined to only send punctuation-free text messages when using Google Assistant?